# Python access dictionary containing lists using a path

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a "complex" (nested with undefined depths and containing lists) json dictionary which stores configuration settings for my project, a snippet of that file:

```
{   
    "system_configuration": {
      "SYSLOGD_ARGS":"-n -O /var/log/messages"
    , "KLOGD_ARGS":"-n"
    , "dbus": {
          "location":"/usr/share/dbus-1/system.d/ab.conf"
        , "services": [
              "com.stezza.ab"
            , "com.stezza.keyboard"
            , "com.stezza.mpd"
            , "com.stezza.remote"
            , "com.stezza.volume" ]
    }
    , "wpa_supplicant": {
          "location":       "/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf"
        , "ctrl_interface": "/var/run/wpa_supplicant"
        , "update_config":  "1"
        , "network": [
              {   "ssid": "OpenWrt"
                , "psk":  "f22da64fa33936391b0ace4d544c63c5b340877327d31ad028296c875c0d8adb" }
            , {   "ssid": "SecondNetwork"
                , "psk":  "f22da64fa33936391b0ace4d544c63c5b340877327d31ad028296c875c0d8adb" } ]
    }
}
```

I load the json file into a dictionary in Python.

What would be the proper way to, given a paths like these:

- "/system_configuration/dbus/1"

  - should return "com.stezza.keyboard"
- "/system_configuration/wpa_supplicant/network/0/ssid"

  - should return "OpenWrt"

(background, probably not relevant, this path will come to me via a flask `<path:>`-url, as part of an RESTful API)

I'm thinking to split the path, loop over it and check if the type is a list to deal with the lists, but I have the feeling there might be a more 'pythonic' way to do this perhaps.

Comment: Have you seen jsonpath? If your query was "$.system_configuration.dbus.1" it would just work.

Comment: Searching jsonpath returns a wealth of useful resources.. having the correct keywords makes all the difference again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can index both dictionaries and list with square brackets, it is not necessary to distinguish between both. AFNP (Ask for Forgiveness, Not Permission) is a pythonic approach for this kind of issues.

```
keys = path.split("/")
acc = json_dict
for key in keys:
    try:
        acc = acc[key]
    except TypeError, KeyError, IndexError:
        acc = None
        break
```

If you expect to always finde the entry in your dictionary, it would make more sense to raise a `ValueError` instead of setting `acc` to `None`. Zen of Python (import this) says you should never let errors pass silently, unless intended to.